# Thickeners with corn syrup consistency

Tags: sauce, thickening

What gives honey, maple syrup and corn syrup it's thick, viscous texture?

I recently used corn syrup for a sauce recipe and really liked the texture it provided. However, I didn't like it's sweetness. **Basically, I am looking for a thickener that has a similar consistency to corn syrup.**

This are 2 options I have thought of so far:

1. guar gum - might not work as my sauce has a high vinegar content, and guar gum does not work well in acidic environments.
2. Chia seeds - the aftertaste may affect the final product

Comment: "What gives honey, maple syrup and corn syrup it's thick, viscous texture?" - sugars.

Comment: Please share what kind of sauce you're trying to thicken.  Without some context, reliable substitutions aren't recommendable.

Comment: It's tomato ketchup. I was following trying out this recipe https://www.chefsteps.com/activities/homemade-heinz-style-ketchup

Comment: In my opinion, there's no good sub for the consistency of syrup. Your best bet is probably to use a higher-concentration vinegar so you can get the same tang but add less water. If you're using corn syrup instead of pure glucose syrup, that will make a difference. Corn syrup is thinner.